# How to set an absolute transform on a Threejs Object3D?

Tags: three.js

I currently have the following code:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const root = new THREE.Group()
scene.matrixAutoUpdate = false
root.matrixAutoUpdate = false
scene.add(root)
```

I put the objects I want to move around under the `root` node. Next I want to set the root node to a certain position in 3D space using a `Matrix4`

The problem is that this has no effect:

```
  root.matrix = translationMatrix
  root.updateMatrixWorld()
```

and the following does an apply of my matrix, but it applies it on top of the existing transform instead of overwriting it.

```
  root.applyMatrix(translationMatrix)
  root.updateMatrixWorld()
```

How do I correctly replace the entire matrix by my own?

Comment: Instead of `root.matrix = translationMatrix;`, did you try `root.matrix.copy(translationMatrix);`?

Comment: Yes, same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the code reveals that `applyMatrix()` decomposes the matrix into position, quaternion and scale. It might be important to set these properties manually:

```
root.matrix = translationMatrix;
root.matrix.decompose(root.position, root.quaternion, root.scale);
```

Another thing: `updateMatrixWorld()` won't do anything when `matrixAutoUpdate` or `matrixWorldNeedsUpdate` is set to `false`. Pass `true` as `force` parameter to update `matrixWorld`:

```
root.updateMatrixWorld(true);
```